What word(s) were used to identify the Van Dyke style of beard in the 17th century?
I am most interested in finding a word used to identify the patch of hair below the lower lip in the Van Dyke style beard, but a word or phrase that describes the hair both above and below the lips will be helpful.
Sample sentence:

The barber shaved off the customer's [Van Dyke beard].

I am writing a work of historical fiction set in the late 17th century and I am trying to use only words that would have been part of the vocabulary of that time.
Using Google books I could not find any reference to the word goatee or Van Dyke (in reference to facial hair) before the end of the 18th century.

Charles I in Three Positions by Anthony van Dyck, from the Royal Collection Trust

A mustache and small goatee?

Cigar-box worthy?

Goole Ngram Viewer shows very little use of 'van Dyke beard' or 'van Dyck beard', but there is a small blip in 'goatee' around the time that Flemish artist passed.


The early modern stage teems with differently coloured beards – red,
black, brown, grey, even blue, purple and yellow – all cut into
various forms – the spade, the pique-devant, the cathedral, the
swallow-tail – each representing its own slice of masculinity which an
audience was expected to decode. A pique-devant, or pointy beard,
became a courtier, while a spade beard suggested a soldier.
‘Greybeard’, meanwhile, was an omnipresent term used to denote ageing
men. Paradoxically the greybeard invoked both wisdom and good counsel
on the one hand and folly and declining faculties on the other.
Depictions of the greybeard show that the benefits of patriarchy such
as economic power and social status were limited, extended only to
those in the prime of manhood.

the beard maketh the man

Portrait of King Charles I of England with a pique-devant
From Wikipedia:
pique-devant
There were alternative forms: pickadevant, pick-a-devant, pickadevaunt, pickdevant, pickedevant, pickerdevant, pike devant, pique de vant
pique-devant (plural pique-devants)
(obsolete, historical) A small beard trimmed to a sharp point.1 [16th–17th c.]
